How to bond a BLE device with a phone using Flutter and flutter_blue package?
I'm developing a Flutter application where I need to connect and bond a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device with a phone. I'm using the flutter_blue package for Bluetooth connectivity. While I can scan for devices and connect to them, I'm struggling with how to handle the bonding process.
Here's a snippet of my code for scanning and connecting to devices:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';

class BluetoothLEManager extends StatefulWidget {
  const BluetoothLEManager({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  BluetoothLEManagerState createState() => BluetoothLEManagerState();
}

class BluetoothLEManagerState extends State<BluetoothLEManager> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
  List<BluetoothDevice> _devices = [];
  bool _isSearching = false;
  bool _scanCompleted = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startBluetoothScan(isInitialScan: true);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flutterBlue.stopScan();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void startBluetoothScan({bool isInitialScan = false}) {
    if (_isSearching) return;

    setState(() {
      _isSearching = true;
      _scanCompleted = false;
    });

    flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10)).then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _isSearching = false;
        _scanCompleted = true;
      });
    });

    flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
      setState(() {
        _devices = results.map((r) => r.device).where((device) => device.name.isNotEmpty).toList();
      });
    });

    flutterBlue.isScanning.listen((isScanning) {
      if (!isScanning) {
        print('Scanning stopped');
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    await device.connect();
    // further code to handle connection and service discovery
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BLE Devices'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _devices.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(_devices[index].name),
            onTap: () => connectToDevice(_devices[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

How do I bond a BLE device with the phone using the flutter_blue package and is there a specific method or process I should follow to ensure the device is bonded before establishing a connection?
Any guidance or example code would be greatly appreciated.
(What I've tried below)
Attempt to Check Bond State and Pair:
I tried to check the bond state of the device and initiate pairing if the device was not already paired. The code snippet I used was:
Future<void> checkAndPairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
  final BondState bondState = await device.bondState.first;

  if (bondState == BondState.bonded) {
    print('Device is already paired');
  } else {
    print('Device is not paired. Attempting to pair...');
    try {
      await device.pair();
      print('Pairing successful');
    } catch (error) {
      print('Pairing failed: $error');
      return;
    }
  }
}

Unfortunately, this approach did not work because the flutter_blue package does not support the bondState and pair methods directly. I encountered errors indicating these methods were undefined.
Switching to flutter_blue_plus Package:
I attempted to switch to the flutter_blue_plus package, which has more features and active maintenance. However, this resulted in numerous type conflicts and compatibility issues between flutter_blue and flutter_blue_plus types, making it impractical to integrate both packages.
Manual Pairing:
I also considered manually prompting the user to pair the devices via the system's Bluetooth settings before initiating the connection in the app. However, this approach does not provide a seamless user experience and does not ensure the app can programmatically verify and handle pairing.

Pairing will be handled automatically by the OS once you try to access a characteristic that needs encryption. Does your BLE device have such a characteristic? If not connecting is enough

@MichaelKotzjan To provide more context, I was attempting to write data to a BLE device, with the ability to choose the format (hex, char, dec, etc.) in my app. When I tried to write a string to a characteristic that expects a string type, it was consistently rejected. I initially thought the issue might be resolved by pairing the BLE device with the phone.
However, it seems the problem lies beyond just pairing.
Thank you for your response. And I don't know if my BLE device do the pairing automatically.

Pairing is simply the exchange of encryption keys and it is not needed if the characteristic does not use any security measures. When the keys are exchanged and afterwards stored for later use we call it bonding. Pairing and Bonding is not needed when making a simple connection. Please try to use a generic BLE exploration tool such as nRF Connect to test your BLE device. If you can't send a string via nRF Connect the problem is your device, not your app

@MichaelKotzjan I believe the core issue is that connecting to the BLE device does not automatically establish bonding between the BLE device and the phone. I tested this using nRF Connect and BLE Scanner, and bonding did not occur automatically. Even manual attempts to bond were unsuccessful. It seems that the BLE device has some form of security feature that prevents bonding altogether.

But do you really need bonding? Isn't connecting enough to read/write the required characteristics?

I was trying to write data to a BLE device to change light brightness. While reading and subscribing to characteristics works fine, writing does not. This seems like a security measure.
The characteristic in question is:
Characteristic Name: uuid_bonding
UUID: 18E446F6-B870-07DD-021A-08123A051401
Properties: Read / WriteNoResp / Write / Notify / Indicate
Value: [225] (bytes)
This characteristic should return [1] if bonded and [0] if not bonded, but I continuously get [255] (ff) upon every connection attempt.

Update: Bonding was indeed necessary to enable writing data to the device.
I have successfully established bonding and can now perform write operations. Thank you for your assistance; it was greatly appreciated.

Great to hear! Feel free to answer your own question and mark it as solved so others can find a solution quicker :)

I'll upload a cleaner solution once I refine it, as the current implementation is quite hardcoded. :) By the way your help was precious and useful.
